# cURL error: [60] for php using IPN from Paypal

Tags: php, curl, certificate, paypal-ipn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

I'm using cpanel to manage a website. I have set up an ipn.php file and an ipnlistener.php file to listen to IPNs from Paypal from my site. I have also set up an ipn_errors.log file to log errors. The error log shows the following error: cURL error: [60] error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /home/wwwplrma/public_html/cert/api_cert_chain.crt
  CApath: none

I don't see any such certificate in the directory public_html. Is there any problem with the permissions for the files or is this error related to something else? The permissions are set as 644 for ipn.php and ipnlistener.php and 775 for ipn_errors.log Thanks in advance!

My code is below:

ipn_errors.log:

> [22-Oct-2012
>   00:32:49] cURL error: [60] error setting certificate verify locations:
>   CAfile: /home/wwwplrma/public_html/cert/api_cert_chain.crt   CApath:
>   none
>
> [22-Oct-2012 00:42:57] cURL error: [60] error setting certificate
>   verify locations:   CAfile:
>   /home/wwwplrma/public_html/cert/api_cert_chain.crt   CApath: none

ipn.php:

```
<?php
/*
ipn.php - example code used for the tutorial:

PayPal IPN with PHP
How To Implement an Instant Payment Notification listener script in PHP
http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html

(c) 2011 - Micah Carrick
*/

// tell PHP to log errors to ipn_errors.log in this directory
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).'/ipn_errors.log');

// intantiate the IPN listener
include('ipnlistener.php');
$listener = new IpnListener();

// tell the IPN listener to use the PayPal test sandbox
$listener->use_sandbox = true;

// try to process the IPN POST
try {
    $listener->requirePostMethod();
    $verified = $listener->processIpn();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    exit(0);
}

if ($verified) {

    $errmsg = '';   // stores errors from fraud checks

    //Check if received verified. Delete later.
    error_log("Post Method Verified");

    // 1. Make sure the payment status is "Completed" 
    if ($_POST['payment_status'] != 'Completed') { 
        // simply ignore any IPN that is not completed
        exit(0); 
    }

    // 2. Make sure seller email matches your primary account email.
    if ($_POST['receiver_email'] != 'support@****.com') {
        $errmsg .= "'receiver_email' does not match: ";
        $errmsg .= $_POST['receiver_email']."\n";
    }

    // 3. Make sure the amount(s) paid match
    if ($_POST['mc_gross'] != '7.00') {
        $errmsg .= "'mc_gross' does not match: ";
        $errmsg .= $_POST['mc_gross']."\n";
    }

    // 4. Make sure the currency code matches

    if ($_POST['mc_currency'] != 'USD') {
        $errmsg .= "'mc_currency' does not match: ";
        $errmsg .= $_POST['mc_currency']."\n";
    }

    // 5. Ensure the transaction is not a duplicate.
    /*
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PW') or exit(0);
    mysql_select_db('DB_NAME') or exit(0);

    $txn_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txn_id']);
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE txn_id = '$txn_id'";
    $r = mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$r) {
      error_log(mysql_error());
       exit(0);
    }

    $exists = mysql_result($r, 0);
    mysql_free_result($r);

    if ($exists) {
        $errmsg .= "'txn_id' has already been processed: ".$_POST['txn_id']."\n";
    }
    */
    if (!empty($errmsg)) {

        // manually investigate errors from the fraud checking
        $body = "IPN failed fraud checks: \n$errmsg\n\n";
        $body .= $listener->getTextReport();
        mail('****@gmail.com', 'IPN Fraud Warning', $body);

    } else {

    //Test email for successful transaction IPN
    mail('****@gmail.com', 'Valid IPN with successful transaction', $listener->getTextReport());
    //error_log($listener->getTextReport());
    /*
        // add this order to a table of completed orders
        $payer_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['payer_email']);
        $mc_gross = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mc_gross']);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO orders VALUES 
                (NULL, '$txn_id', '$payer_email', $mc_gross)";

        if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
            error_log(mysql_error());
            exit(0);
        }

        // send user an email with a link to their digital download
        $to = filter_var($_POST['payer_email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $subject = "Your digital download is ready";
        mail($to, "Thank you for your order", "Download URL: ...");
        */

    }

} else {
    //Check if received. Delete later
     error_log("Post Method Unverified");
    // manually investigate the invalid IPN
    mail('****@gmail.com', 'Invalid IPN', $listener->getTextReport());
}

?>
```

ipnlistener.php:

```
<?php
/**
 *  PayPal IPN Listener
 *
 *  A class to listen for and handle Instant Payment Notifications (IPN) from 
 *  the PayPal server.
 *
 *  https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN
 *
 *  @package    PHP-PayPal-IPN
 *  @author     Micah Carrick
 *  @copyright  (c) 2012 - Micah Carrick
 *  @version    2.1.0
 */
class IpnListener {

    /**
     *  If true, the recommended cURL PHP library is used to send the post back 
     *  to PayPal. If flase then fsockopen() is used. Default true.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $use_curl = true;     

    /**
     *  If true, explicitly sets cURL to use SSL version 3. Use this if cURL
     *  is compiled with GnuTLS SSL.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $force_ssl_v3 = true;     

    /**
     *  If true, cURL will use the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to follow any 
     *  "Location: ..." headers in the response.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $follow_location = false;     

    /**
     *  If true, an SSL secure connection (port 443) is used for the post back 
     *  as recommended by PayPal. If false, a standard HTTP (port 80) connection
     *  is used. Default true.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $use_ssl = true;      

    /**
     *  If true, the paypal sandbox URI www.sandbox.paypal.com is used for the
     *  post back. If false, the live URI www.paypal.com is used. Default false.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $use_sandbox = false; 
    /**
     *  The amount of time, in seconds, to wait for the PayPal server to respond
     *  before timing out. Default 30 seconds.
     *
     *  @var int
     */
    public $timeout = 30;       

    private $post_data = array();
    private $post_uri = '';     
    private $response_status = '';
    private $response = '';

    const PAYPAL_HOST = 'www.paypal.com';
    const SANDBOX_HOST = 'www.sandbox.paypal.com';

    /**
     *  Post Back Using cURL
     *
     *  Sends the post back to PayPal using the cURL library. Called by
     *  the processIpn() method if the use_curl property is true. Throws an
     *  exception if the post fails. Populates the response, response_status,
     *  and post_uri properties on success.
     *
     *  @param  string  The post data as a URL encoded string
     */
    protected function curlPost($encoded_data) {

        if ($this->use_ssl) {
            $uri = 'https://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
            $this->post_uri = $uri;
        } else {
            $uri = 'http://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
            $this->post_uri = $uri;
        }

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 
                    dirname(__FILE__)."/cert/api_cert_chain.crt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $this->follow_location);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

        if ($this->force_ssl_v3) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
        }

        $this->response = curl_exec($ch);
        $this->response_status = strval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));

        if ($this->response === false || $this->response_status == '0') {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Post Back Using fsockopen()
     *
     *  Sends the post back to PayPal using the fsockopen() function. Called by
     *  the processIpn() method if the use_curl property is false. Throws an
     *  exception if the post fails. Populates the response, response_status,
     *  and post_uri properties on success.
     *
     *  @param  string  The post data as a URL encoded string
     */
    protected function fsockPost($encoded_data) {

        if ($this->use_ssl) {
            $uri = 'ssl://'.$this->getPaypalHost();
            $port = '443';
            $this->post_uri = $uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        } else {
            $uri = $this->getPaypalHost(); // no "http://" in call to fsockopen()
            $port = '80';
            $this->post_uri = 'http://'.$uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        }

        $fp = fsockopen($uri, $port, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout);

        if (!$fp) { 
            // fsockopen error
            throw new Exception("fsockopen error: [$errno] $errstr");
        } 

        $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $header .= "Host: ".$this->getPaypalHost()."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($encoded_data)."\r\n";
        $header .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

        fputs($fp, $header.$encoded_data."\r\n\r\n");

        while(!feof($fp)) { 
            if (empty($this->response)) {
                // extract HTTP status from first line
                $this->response .= $status = fgets($fp, 1024); 
                $this->response_status = trim(substr($status, 9, 4));
            } else {
                $this->response .= fgets($fp, 1024); 
            }
        } 

        fclose($fp);
    }

    private function getPaypalHost() {
        if ($this->use_sandbox) return self::SANDBOX_HOST;
        else return self::PAYPAL_HOST;
    }

    /**
     *  Get POST URI
     *
     *  Returns the URI that was used to send the post back to PayPal. This can
     *  be useful for troubleshooting connection problems. The default URI
     *  would be "ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com:443/cgi-bin/webscr"
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getPostUri() {
        return $this->post_uri;
    }

    /**
     *  Get Response
     *
     *  Returns the entire response from PayPal as a string including all the
     *  HTTP headers.
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getResponse() {
        return $this->response;
    }

    /**
     *  Get Response Status
     *
     *  Returns the HTTP response status code from PayPal. This should be "200"
     *  if the post back was successful. 
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getResponseStatus() {
        return $this->response_status;
    }

    /**
     *  Get Text Report
     *
     *  Returns a report of the IPN transaction in plain text format. This is
     *  useful in emails to order processors and system administrators. Override
     *  this method in your own class to customize the report.
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getTextReport() {

        $r = '';

        // date and POST url
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n[".date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - '.$this->getPostUri();
        if ($this->use_curl) $r .= " (curl)\n";
        else $r .= " (fsockopen)\n";

        // HTTP Response
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n{$this->getResponse()}\n";

        // POST vars
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n";

        foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
            $r .= str_pad($key, 25)."$value\n";
        }
        $r .= "\n\n";

        return $r;
    }

    /**
     *  Process IPN
     *
     *  Handles the IPN post back to PayPal and parsing the response. Call this
     *  method from your IPN listener script. Returns true if the response came
     *  back as "VERIFIED", false if the response came back "INVALID", and 
     *  throws an exception if there is an error.
     *
     *  @param array
     *
     *  @return boolean
     */    
    public function processIpn($post_data=null) {

        $encoded_data = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        if ($post_data === null) { 
            // use raw POST data 
            if (!empty($_POST)) {
                $this->post_data = $_POST;
                $encoded_data .= '&'.file_get_contents('php://input');
            } else {
                throw new Exception("No POST data found.");
            }
        } else { 
            // use provided data array
            $this->post_data = $post_data;

            foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
                $encoded_data .= "&$key=".urlencode($value);
            }
        }

        if ($this->use_curl) $this->curlPost($encoded_data); 
        else $this->fsockPost($encoded_data);

        if (strpos($this->response_status, '200') === false) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid response status: ".$this->response_status);
        }

        if (strpos($this->response, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
            return true;
        } elseif (strpos($this->response, "INVALID") !== false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected response from PayPal.");
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Require Post Method
     *
     *  Throws an exception and sets a HTTP 405 response header if the request
     *  method was not POST. 
     */    
    public function requirePostMethod() {
        // require POST requests
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
            header('Allow: POST', true, 405);
            throw new Exception("Invalid HTTP request method.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @hakre Thanks for your reply! I have edited my question to differentiate it. :)

Comment: **Class 'IpnListener' not found** - the certificate is not much of your problem (yet?).

Comment: Actually, that error was there yesterday because the ipnlistener.php file had coding errors. This problem was fixed yesterday itself and is no longer there. You can see the newer errors using the timestamps. The newest errors are at the bottom

Comment: Remove the noise out of your question then because this then isn't related to your *concrete* problem any longer. Also I suggest you put the error messages (the ones that count now) *above* the example code.

Comment: Done the edits, thanks for helping me to post questions well. I'm new to stackoverflow. :)

Comment: Please double-check with the documentation, e.g. this info [from `curl_setopt()` page](http://php.net/curl_setopt): *"`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` - `FALSE` to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate. Alternate certificates to verify against can be specified with the `CURLOPT_CAINFO` option or a certificate directory can be specified with the `CURLOPT_CAPATH` option."* You might miss to use one of the needed options, I suspect `CURLOPT_CAPATH` however that is just an assumption. Please check your own if you like.

Comment: Does the file `/home/wwwplrma/public_html/cert/api_cert_chain.crt` exist with the right permissions?

Comment: @Jack Thanks a lot! I hadn't installed the certificate. I have installed it now and the IPN is working as expected for now. :)

Comment: @hakre Thanks for leading me to the answer. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since this helped you I will add it as an answer; hopefully it will help others too, but I somehow doubt it :)

The code in `ipnlistener.php` uses `CURLOPT_CAINFO` to specify the path to a certificate chain and therefore must exist on the server:

```
/home/wwwplrma/public_html/cert/api_cert_chain.crt
```